# kendo ui grid date filter only by month and year

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, grid, kendo-grid, kendo-datepicker

I already implemented kendo ui grid date filter like below;

```
<kendo:grid-column title="Payment Date" field="paymentDate" width="160px" format="{0:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss}">
                            
    <kendo:grid-column-filterable>
        <kendo:grid-column-filterable-ui>
            <script>
                function dateFilter(e) {
                    e.kendoDatePicker({
                        format: "MMMM yyyy",
                        depth: "year",
                        start: "year"
                    });
                }
            </script>
        </kendo:grid-column-filterable-ui>
    </kendo:grid-column-filterable>
                                
</kendo:grid-column>
```

It successfully brings out date filter popup and able to select month and year but the problem is when I select for example with operator *"Is equal" to "January 2021"* it returns probably the first of January instead of returning values only in January 2021.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can change the filter before it is performed with [`filter`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/events/filter) event:

```
filter: function(e) {
  if (e.filter !== null) {
    let addDate = null;
    e.filter.filters.forEach(filter => {
      if (filter.field === 'paymentDate') {
        // Change default filter value to first day of month
        filter.value = new Date(filter.value.getFullYear(), filter.value.getMonth(), 1);
        // Change default filter operator from 'eq' to 'gt'
        filter.operator = 'gt';
        
        // Add a new filter for the last day of the month outside the loop
        addDate = filter.value;
      }
    });
    
    if (addDate) {
      e.filter.filters.push({
        field: 'paymentDate',
        operator: 'lt',
        value: new Date(addDate.getFullYear(), (addDate.getMonth() + 1), -1)
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Working demo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.2.616/styles/kendo.default-v2.min.css"/>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.2.616/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
<div id="grid"></div>
<script>
  $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    columns: [
      { field: "name" },
      { field: "age" },
      { field: "paymentDate", 
        format: "{0:d}", 
        filterable: {
          ui: function(element) {
            element.kendoDatePicker({
              format: "MMMM yyyy",
              depth: "year",
              start: "year"
            });
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    dataSource: {
      data: [
        { id: 1, name: "Jane Doe", age: 30, paymentDate: new Date(2021, 8, 10) },
        { id: 2, name: "John Doe", age: 33, paymentDate: new Date(2021, 7, 10) }
      ],
      schema: {
        model: { id: "id" },
      }
    },
    filterable: {
      extra: false
    },
    filter: function(e) {
      if (e.filter !== null) {
        let addDate = null;
        e.filter.filters.forEach(filter => {
          if (filter.field === 'paymentDate') {
            // Change default filter value to first day of month
            filter.value = new Date(filter.value.getFullYear(), filter.value.getMonth(), 1);
            // Change default filter operator from 'eq' to 'gt'
            filter.operator = 'gt';
            
            // Add a new filter for the last day of the month outside the loop
            addDate = filter.value;
          }
        });
        
        if (addDate) {
          e.filter.filters.push({
            field: 'paymentDate',
            operator: 'lt',
            value: new Date(addDate.getFullYear(), (addDate.getMonth() + 1), -1)
          });
        }
      }
    }
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/)

Comment: thanks for the answer, the issue is, grid that I am working is on is a huge grid and it is only implemented in jsp and columns are also in jsp